# Resizing Chessboard using Graphics

Tags: c#, graphics, rectangles

I have project for school to make chessboard and figures using `Graphics` that will resize when I resize the `Form`. I wanted to make 2 variables:

- `new_width = currentFormWidth/startingFormWidth` and
- `new_height = currentFormHeight/startingFormHeight`

... and on resize to multiply those width and height with figures and board width and height, but because I used `Rectangle`-s I can't multiply with float. Any other suggestions? Here is code and screenshot

```
 grafik = this.CreateGraphics();
        float new_width = this.Width / startingWidth;
        float new__height = this.Height / startingHeight;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0) || (j % 2 != 0 && i % 2 != 0))
                    grafik.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.NavajoWhite), i * 65, j * 65, 65*new_width, 65*new__height);
                else if ((j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 != 0) || (j % 2 != 0 && i % 2 == 0))
                    grafik.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DarkRed), i * 65, j * 65, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height);
            }
        }

        /*************************BLACK FIGURES************************/
        //ROOKS
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(0, 0, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 2, 2, 65 , 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 7, 0, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 2, 2, 65 , 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        //HORSES
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(60, 0, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 3, 2, 65 , 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 6, 0, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 3, 2, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        //BISHOPS
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 2, 0, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 4, 2, 65 , 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 5, 0, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 4, 2, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        //KING AND QUEEN
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 4, 0, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(0, 2, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 3, 0, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65, 2, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        //PAWNS
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * i, 65,65*new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 5, 2, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        /*************************WHITE FIGURES************************/
        //ROOKS
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(0, 65 * 7, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 2, 65, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 7, 65 * 7, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 2, 65, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        //HORSES
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(60, 65 * 7, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 3, 65, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 6, 65 * 7, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 3, 65, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        //BISHOPS
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 2, 65 * 7, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 4, 65, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 5, 65 * 7, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 4, 65, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        //KING AND QUEEN
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 4, 65 * 7, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(0, 65, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * 3, 65 * 7, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65, 65, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        //PAWNS
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            grafik.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.figure, new Rectangle(65 * i, 65 * 6, 65 * new_width, 65 * new__height), new Rectangle(65 * 5, 65, 65, 65), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
```

[image: screenshot of starting position]

Comment: Use [RectangleF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectanglef?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

Comment: ... and why are you creating Graphics objects? `grafik = this.CreateGraphics();` ... Handle the `Paint` event instead and use the supported `e.Graphics` object to draw.

Comment: What is difference between Paint event and Graphics objects?

Comment: You can't compare a cat with a car buddy. However, the `Paint` event provides a free `Graphics` object in the `PaintEventArgs` for you to draw. So, you don't need to create additional `Graphics` objects as such and flood the memory with them.

Comment: Also, In some situations, when you need to create any disposable object like `Graphics`, make sure you create it in `using { .. }` block, or make sure to `.Dispose();` it when you finish.